# How to roughly estimate the size of archives log generated using an Oracle NOARCHIVELOG instance

Tags: oracle

The question may sounds odd, but here's the thing: I'm trying to estimate the amount of archive log that a PL/SQL procedure will generate when deployed to production. I'm on a DEV DB running in NOARCHIVELOG mode and there is no chance to have an ARCHIVELOG mode enabled instance available for testing.

What views may be worth look at for getting some figures that may be useful for getting a rough idea of the amount or archive log that will be generated in case the ARCHIVELOG mode is enabled? The DEV database is an 19c Enterprise Edition.

Comment: You would need to generate a comparable number of transactions (insert/update/delete) in the database to simulate a production workload, then look at how often you switch redo logs. In archivelog mode, every time you switch logs you'll generate an archive log of the same size as the redo log.

Comment: Note that if you have more than one archive log destination configured, you'll generate one archive log copy in *each* destination for redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you aren't using any parallel DML (PDML), you can utilize `v$sesstat` to get your sessions' `redo size` counter before the activity, then query it again to get the counter after your activity, and the difference is the amount of redo your process generated. As long as you have one archive log dest that will be how much archive log space you can expect to consume in production.

```
DECLARE
  var_start_redo integer;
  var_end_redo integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT ss.value
    INTO var_start_redo
    FROM v$sesstat ss,
         v$statname sn
   WHERE ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#
     AND sn.name = 'redo size'
     AND ss.sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');

   // DO STUFF

  SELECT ss.value
    INTO var_end_redo
    FROM v$sesstat ss,
         v$statname sn
   WHERE ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#
     AND sn.name = 'redo size'
     AND ss.sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');

  dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(var_end_redo - var_start_redo)|| ' redo bytes generated');
END;
```

The # of archive logs that would spin off, if that mattered, could be calculated by dividing by the redo logfile size (`v$log.bytes`).

If you *are* using parallel DML, it's a lot harder because the session info you need is available only for the lifetime of each PX slave which ends at the end of a DML operation, so you can't do the "before and after" picture synchronously. The only way to get those numbers is to have a monitor process external to your app polling frequently (e.g. every second) on `v$sesstat` for the set of `SID`s (and `INST_ID` from `gv$sesstat` if RAC) for the PX slaves in question, which you can get from joining `gv$px_session` and `gv$session` on the QC fields. The goal here is to get the maximum value (or close to it) of that redo counter before the session is gone, which would be the last polling event that still finds data. But it's probably a lot easier just to disable parallel DML so you don't have to do all this, as the amount of redo shouldn't be appreciably different with and without parallel DML in effect.

Alternatively, *if* the dev system is quiet and *nothing else* is happening on it, you can assume your block changes are the only ones happening and simply use system-level counters by substituting `v$sysstat` for `v$sesstat`. That would cover anything PX slaves did under parallel DML mode and would also not require you to instrument the code itself.